# How to use async await function object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Say I have a function object-

```
setObj : function(a,b){
    obj.a = a;
    obj.b = b;
}
```

If I have to use async & await on this function object, how do I do it?

If the same was written in function (function way), say-

```
async function setObj(a,b){
    obj.a = a;
    obj.b = b;
}

await setObj(2,3);
```

This works fine. But, how do I do it in case of function object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use the `async` keyword in front of the method declaration:

```
let obj = {};
let myObj = {
    async setObj(a,b) {
        obj.a = a;
        obj.b = b;
    }
}
```

See http://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-methods

**UPDATE**

You cannot use `await` outside of an async function. In order to use this you have to wrap that call to `await setObj(2, 3)`:

```
async function consoleLog() {
    await myObj.setObj(2, 3);
    console.log(obj.a + obj.b);
}

consoleLog();
```

Comment: It says missing : after property id. This is what I have tried- https://gist.github.com/bozzmob/a36f0d28310df88f0a5d

Comment: In your Gist, move the `async` keyword in front of "function" after the ":"

Comment: See my comments in your Gist, you are using the "await" keyword wrong, it must be inside an async function.

Comment: Please have a look at the "Update 1" in gist. I am getting the following error on doing the changes - SyntaxError: missing } after property list.

Comment: Ben's spot on. Check out my updated answer which works with your code.

Comment: You can use the Babel REPL to try this, I have set it up for you: http://tinyurl.com/zzvrzmv

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you! I did learn more than 1 way of doing this. :)

Comment: Specifying a key din't work `func1:   async func1() {}`. Excellent, searched all over the internet. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Use the same `async` keyword in your object's property:

```
(async function () {
  var obj = {};
  console.log("hello");

  let setObj = async function (a,b){
    obj.a = a;
    obj.b = b;
  };

  await setObj(2,3);

  console.log(obj.a+obj.b);
})();
```

Note that the entire code is wrapped in an asynchronous self-invoking function. This is needed, otherwise the `await setObj` will not be able to run correctly.

Comment: I tried this approach, I get an error saying a semicolon is missing. Have a look at my code- https://gist.github.com/bozzmob/f5ef1c0eff9d7e7f853d

Comment: Is setObj a property inside an object? For example: let someFunctions = {setObj: async function (a, b) {...}};. Your code won't run in the gist, since you're using a colon outside of an object. Alternately, you can do let setObj = async function (a, b) {...};

Comment: Please check "Update 1" on the same link(https://gist.github.com/bozzmob/f5ef1c0eff9d7e7f853d) Still facing the same issue.

Comment: And "Update 2" as well. I have tried both the solutions you told. Please can you update your current answer here with the working solution?

Answer (score 4):

using arrow functions work as well

```
const myObject = {
   myFunc: async () => {
     await myResultHere
   }
}
```

using this: Since the function is an async function, it will run asynchronously. If you want to run this with await, you will have to use it inside an async function

```
const useFunc = async () => {
   const res = await myObject.myfunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the `async` keyword on any function, not only function declarations but also function expressions and methods of object. For example:

**As an method of an object:**

```
const Object = {
    async asyncFunction() {
        await MyExamplepromise
    }
}
```

**As a variable:**

```
const myFunc = async function () { await MyExamplepromise }

// this is how execute the function expression
// first () operator to execute, and use .then get access the resolved value
myFunc().then((val) => { console.log(val) })
```

---

Also notice that an async function returns a promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.