# Manipulate data from an async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have two functions,

```
function getRequest(url, api_key, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + api_key);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            document.getElementById("droplets").textContent = error;
        }
    });
}

function getDroplets(url, api_key) {
    var request = getRequest(url, api_key, function(response) {
        var droplets = response.droplets;
        var numDroplets = droplets.length;
        return {
            droplets: droplets,
            numDroplets: numDroplets
        };
    });
    alert(request);
}
```

I want to have another function, let's call it `listDroplets`, that will call `getDroplets()` and manipulate the data returned from it. I'm not sure how to do this because `getDroplets` has an asynchronous call within it.

EDIT: I have tried the following, but it still doesn't work.

```
async function listDroplets() {
    await getDroplets(api_url, api_key);
    alert(request.numDroplets);
}
```

Comment: But also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210812/how-to-use-async-await-function-object-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: getRequest should return `$.ajax(...` drop the success and error. In getDroplets you can do `getrequest(...).then(result=>{return alteredResult}).then(finalResult=>...).catch(error=>handle your error)` currently getting a request (called getRequest) is implementing something that getDroplets should implement (when there is an error)

Comment: @mplungjan see my updated post

Comment: @HMR how would I return the result if success is what's called when the Ajax request is successful?

Comment: reopened, but still a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a promise like object, you can try to have a look at promises, change your code and if that doesn't work edit the question again for us to have a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are how your functions could return promise like objects that you can use in an async await function:

```
function getRequest(url, api_key, callback) {
  //to escape terrible jQuery Deferred and comfortably continue in Promise land
  // you can do
  // const deferred = $.ajax(...); return Promise.resolve(deferred)
  return $.ajax({//return promise like object
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + api_key);
    }
  });
}

function getDroplets(url, api_key) {
  return getRequest(url, api_key)//return promise like object
  .then(function (response) {//
    var droplets = response.droplets;
    var numDroplets = droplets.length;
    return {
      droplets: droplets,
      numDroplets: numDroplets
    };
  })
  .catch(function (error) {//implement error if something goes wrong
    console.log(error);
    document.getElementById("droplets").textContent = error;
  });
}


async function listDroplets() {
  //depending on how old your jQuery is you may want to do this:
  // await Promise.resolve(getDroplets(api_url, api_key));
  const request = await getDroplets(api_url, api_key);
  //note that if something goes wrong then request is undefined (depending on jQuery version)
  alert(request.numDroplets);
}
```

Comment: What is jQuery deferred?

Comment: @JordanBaron [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) is a promise like object that jQuery created before the Promise standard was finalized, especially older implementations of it have behaviors that are not like standard promises as we now know today. Even if you want to support Internet Explorer (does not have native Promises) I'd advice getting a good polyfil and wrap the deferred in a `Promise.resolve(some deferred like $.ajax(...))`.