# Return value with asynchronous functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have the following TS function:

```
CheckRegUser(u: User): boolean {
    let b: boolean = true;
    let toSend = {
      email: u.email
    };
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/", toSend).subscribe((data: Valid) => {
      if(!data.validity){
        b = false;
      }
    });
    console.log(b);
    return b;
}
```

Here I am connecting to an ExpressJS backend and I am getting back a boolean result. This part is working fine, but the problem is that the "return b" statement is executed before that the value of b is changed in "this.http", so b is always true no matter what the response from Express is.

I know that TS and JS are asynchronous and this problem is caused because of that, but I couldn't find the correct method to solve my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210812/how-to-use-async-await-function-object-in-javascript#34210944

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try with `async await`

```
  async CheckRegUser(u: User): Promise<boolean> {

    let toSend = {
      email: u.email
    };
    let k = await this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/", toSend).subscribe((data: Valid){
      let b: boolean = true;
      if(!data.validity){
        b = false;
      }
      return b
    });
    console.log(k);
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Note that this means that `CheckRegUser` will return not `boolean`, but `Promise<boolean>`, and it should be handled correspondingly in the calling code (either through `then`, or also with `async/await`).

Comment: @Cerberus I agree with you the return of `async/await` is a promise

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it solved my problem!! And thanks @Cerberus for pointing out that async returned a promise.

Comment: A promise is NOT a value! Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: @iGanja beacuse `async` functions return Promises?

Answer (score 4):

I had this common problem when I was just starting to learn Observables/Reactive programming with a Google Maps app as well :D!

Spot on, you realised that asynchronous function hasn't mutated the `b` boolean flag yet when the function synchronously returns `b` (that defaulted to `true`);

To fix this it might be easier to restructure your function to return the `Observable` to the caller.

and maybe look up `Observable` chaining or similar concept `Promise` chaining.

Old example:

```js
CheckRegUser(u: User): boolean {
    const b: boolean = true;
    const toSend = {
      email: u.email
    };

    const httpPost: Observable<aJsonObject> = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/", toSend)
    const httpPostSubscription: Subscription = httpPost
      .subscribe((data: Valid) => { // This is asynchronous
        if (!data.validity) {
          b = false;
        }
      });
    console.log(b);

    return b; // This is effectively sync returning your default value `b = true`;
  }
```

It would be better if you could rename your variables to be clearer.
`b` or `isDataValid`.
Might also be good practice to start functional-style with `const` variables to help avoid mutability issues.

If you're more familiar with `Promises`, you could also try to `promisify` the httpClient.post Observable.

General gist of it is to pass the `Observable` back to the caller and `.subscribe` it there.
When something is returning asynchronously, you should return the asynchronicity all the way back to the top.

Refactor code to reflect these practices

```js
  CheckRegUser(user: User, httpClient: HttpClient): Observable<Valid> {
    // 1. Data to send
    type  EmailPost                  = { email: string }
    const emailJsonToSend: EmailPost = { // I prefer explicit typing wherever possible :tada: :D
      email: user.email
    };

    // 2. POST the data to the web server
    const emailHttpPostObs: Observable<Valid> = httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/", emailJsonToSend);

    return emailHttpPostObs;
  }

  CallerSubmitUserFunction(user: User, httpClient: HttpClient) {
    // Made some assumptions, please comment and we can work out a better solution
    // Explicitly typed things as an example.

    // 1. You have a user e.g. new User(name:'myUser', email: 'myEmailAddressOrEmailContent@email.com');
    const userToSend: User = user;
    // 2. You POST the user.email and get response.
    const validatedUserDataObs: Observable<Valid> = CheckRegUser(userToSend, httpClient);

    // 3. You check whether the server accepted the data and whether it was valid.
    const validatedUserDataObs: Subscription = validatedUserDataObs
      .subscribe((data: Valid) => {
        // Perform data validation or Error checking here.

        // If data is valid, 
        if (dataValidationFunction()) {
          // Do something here
          // Instead of trying to return the boolean in the asynchronouse function.
          // Directly do something after the server responds (whenever it happens).
        }
      }) // catch Error


    // It would also be better if you could rename your variables to be more self-indicative
    // var dataIsValid

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, it is really well explained, but I preferred to have a simple and clear solution for my problem. But again, thank you for the effort you put to write this answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can return the entire document after pulling it from DB

Refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

```
export const getUserWishList = async (user: string): Promise<WishDoc> => {
  let wish = await Wish.findOne({ user });
  if (!wish) {
    wish = Wish.build({
      user,
      list: [],
    });
    await wish.save();
  }
  return wish;
};
```

Async functions always return a promise.

```
const wishList = await getUserWishList(req.currentUser?.id!);
```