# Angular wait for promise to resolve before proceeding

Tags: angular, promise

My following code is part of the validation portion of a project. The purpose of this piece of code is to check if a value exists in a reference table. If does exist, then ok to proceed. If not, throw error and stop the user.

```
saveChanges() {
    //blah blah
    if (needTovalidate){
    passedCheck = false;
    this.validationService.checkExistence(value)
    .then((exist: boolean) => {
      passedCheck = exist;
      console.log("INSIDE: " + exist);

    });
    console.log("OUTSIDE: " + passedCheck);

    if(passedCheck) {
        //Rest of code
    } else {
        //Throw error msg
    }
}


public async checkExistence(value: string): Promise<boolean>{
  var exist = false;
  return this.getRefData().then((rec: dataModel[]) => {
    return rec.some(el => {
      return el.col1 === value;
    });
  });
}

private async getRefData() {
  return await this.configurationService.retrieveTableData().toPromise(); 
}
```

Expected Log:

```
INSIDE: true
OUTSIDE:true
```

Actual Log:

```
OUTSIDE: false
INSIDE: true
```

Obviously, the code did not wait for the boolean promise to resolve before it proceeds to the next line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the rest of your code INSIDE the `.then()` handler.  That's the ONLY place the boolean from the promise is valid.  This is an asynchronous operation.  The `.then()` handler is called some indeterminate time in the future.  The rest of your function after the `.then()` handler executes BEFORE the promise finishes and before the `.then()` handler is called.  So, the only place to use the promise result is inside the `.then()` handler.  There are probably more than 1000 other examples of this same kind of question here so lots of dups if you want to search.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I've seen quite some posts as well, but was not sure if my case is somewhat different by any chance...Thank you.

Comment: It's not different.  Assigning a value, obtained in an asynchronous callback to a higher scoped variable so you can "hopefully" us it elsewhere is nearly always a mistake in node.js.  That is a glaring warning sign that you're doing it wrong.  Use the value IN the callback where you get it or pass it to another function you call from within that callback.  That's how you program asynchronous code in node.js.

Comment: Also `return await xxxx()` is a waste.  Just do `return xxxx()`.  They're both returning a promise that will be resolved with the appropriate value.  You will have to use `.then()` on the returned promise to get the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jfriend00 mentions in your comment discussions that this is a dupe of similar questions, whenever using asynchronous functions (`Promise`, `Observable`) you should bubble up the asynchronicity back to the call and `.then` or `.subscribe` it there.

[Return value with asynchronous functions in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166423/return-value-with-asynchronous-functions-in-typescript/51166777#51166777)

> Any suggestions?

You could alter your `saveChanges` and `checkExistence` function in a similar way to this:

Please see the example below <sub>and maybe clean up your question example code in an edit (if not rewriting to make a better example question, I believe you at least may resolve your issue yourself in the process by taking the time to go over it painstakingly again)</sub>

There are a couple of issues with the pseudocode you have provided, but I tried to conceptualise the process as best I could while remaining true to your original code.

```js
saveChanges(needToValidate: boolean, // ??
  changesToValidate: Changes,
  asyncValidateFunction: (changes: Changes) => Promise < boolean > , // hmm
) {

  asyncValidateFunction(changesToValidate);
  //blah blah
  if (needToValidate) { // Random context here? Feels like too many things going on in one. Try to isolate functionality.
    this.validationService.checkExistence(value)
      .then(
        (exist: boolean) => {
          yourStuffToDoAfterPassedCheckValidation(exist) // hmm
          console.log("INSIDE: " + exist); // be safe and stay inside :)
        }
      );

  }
}

// Tried to encapsulate as much as your original concept and style from original question. 
// Please refactor this based on your understanding
yourStuffToDoAfterPassedCheckValidation(passedCheckFlag: boolean) {
  if (passedCheckFlag) {
    // Rest of code
  } else {
    // Throw error msg
  }
}

public checkExistence(value: string): Promise < boolean > {
  // Unused junk code? var exist = false;

  return this.getRefData()
    .then(
      (rec: dataModel[]) => {
        return rec
          .some(el => {
            return el.col1 === value;
          });
      });
}
```

As this is in Angular, would this perhaps be related to Angular forms? [Async validators might be helpful to you even if not directly related](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions)

Similar question to [Return value with asynchronous functions in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166423/return-value-with-asynchronous-functions-in-typescript/) and perhaps many others
I see similar inconsistencies in these types of questions that could be improved with explicit typing in `TypeScript` to provide quicker feedback of things to guard against things going wrong!

If you want more specific help, please provide a refactored version of your original code, because some things were seemed weakly replaced.

Otherwise, we could work off pseudocode with more clarity. 
As this seems to be a a duplicate question making similar async mistakes, it is up to you to provide the context in which your code is not working, otherwise comprehensive answers are already available in the other questions .

In troubleshooting tangled code, it might help you to rewrite the whole program flow as pseudocode first and then regenerate the code based on that to consolidate what you are trying to understand. <sub>(This is why I sometimes recommend handwriting your program, or, at the very least, break down everything into assigned variables, explicitly type everything and make as much use of the `TypeScript` Language service as you can.</sub>

**Edit:** I see you had *already* duplicated your own question that is a bit clearer and is working towards fixing your issues. I wish you would've just updated your question in one place though. From the comments in your other questions you do not seem to want to follow suggestions to the fundamental asynchronous usages of `Promise` and still want to depend on a mutated value that does not exist yet (asynchronous).

Comment: My comment might've been a bit harsh. You're new to reactive programming and I would recommend that you just follow a couple of small tutorials using Promises first to get the feel of it. Also get comfortable withObservables because I think you may encounter more issues depending on your service and trying to promisify everything could make it more complex. (preference). Couple of hours on those tutorials instead of properly formatting QA on Stack Overflow might be more productive for you to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I use, is to create a boolean variable and make it false in `then` and `catch`

Example:

```
let isPromisePending = false;

function someFn() {
  isPromisePending = true;
  myPromise().then(() => {
    isPromisePending = false;
    //Success handler below
  }).catch(() => {
    isPromisePending = false;
    //Error handler below
  })
}
```